# How to print the actual bitonic subsequence?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an array arr[0 … n-1] containing n positive integers, a subsequence of arr[] is called Bitonic if it is first increasing, then decreasing. Write a function that takes an array as argument and returns the length of the longest bitonic subsequence.

Input arr[] = {1, 11, 2, 10, 4, 5, 2, 1};
Output: 6 (A Longest Bitonic Subsequence of length 6 is 1, 2, 10, 4, 2, 1)

Now, for finding out the length, I calculated first the length of LIS (Longest Inc. Subsequence) and then the length of the LDS (Longest Dec. Subsequence) and then traversed over both the arrays, while doing `max(lis[i] + lds[i]-1)` where `i varies from 0 to (n-1)`.

```
for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )   // Code for LIS
{
    for ( j = 0; j < i; j++ )
    {
        if (arr[i] > arr[j] && lis[i] < lis[j] + 1)
            lis[i] = lis[j] + 1;
    }
}

for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )   // Code for LDS
{
    for ( j = 0; j < i; j++ )
    {
        if (arr[i]  < arr[j] && lds[i] < lds[j] + 1)
            lds[i] = lds[j] + 1;
    }
}
```

Now, if I am asked to print the actual bitonic subsequence, how can I do that? One way I thought of is to find out the index where maximum occurs. Now, I know the values of LIS and LDS at that index and then, I print the LIS and LDS from that index. But, I couldn't really formulate this idea properly.

Comment: Shouldn't you calculate the LDS as a LIS from the back? Otherwise, I doubt that the `max(lis[i] + lds[i]-1)` is correct. Anyway, if you update `lis[i]` or `lds[i]`, you can also update a pointer to the previous element (`lisPointer[i] = j`). Then you can traverse this chain back from the point of interest.

Comment: No, somehow when I calculate `lds` from the front, it gives the correct answer of `lds[i] + lis[i] - 1`. Though, intuitively, it should be calculated from the back, but somehow, it gives the correct value.

Comment: @JohnLui You get the right result by coincidence: at position of the value `5` the `lis` is 4 and the `lds` is 3, so you get `4+3-1=6`. However, it would be easy to construct an example for which this solution would produce a wrong result: `{1, 2, 3, 2, 1}` should return 5, but it would return 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is spot-on. When you compute the maximum length as `max(lis[i] + lds[i]-1)`, store `i` of the actual maximum, where the sequence changes from increasing to decreasing. Let's call it `maxIndex`.

Now you can produce the sequence as follows:

- Start at `prev=maxIndex, i=maxIndex-1`, and go down in the order of decreasing indexes until you find `lis[i]==lis[prev]-1 && arr[i] < arr[prev]`.
- Store `arr[i]` in the result list `res`, set `prev=i`, and continue searching down the array
- Stop when you reach `lis[i]==1`.
- Invert the `res` list
- Add `arr[maxIndex]` to `res`
- Start at `prev=maxIndex, i=maxIndex+1`, and go up the array until you find `lds[i]==lis[prev]-1 && arr[i] < arr[prev]`
- Store `arr[i]` in the result list `res`, set `prev=i`, and continue searching down the array
- Stop when you reach `lds[i]==1`.

This approach uses `lis` and `lds` arrays to reconstruct both portions of the bitonic sequence. Since the first part of the sequence needs to be retrieved in reverse order, the portion of the list from 0 to `maxIndex` needs to be reversed.

Comment: Also, I want to ask, am I wrong in calculating `lds[i]` by traversing the array from front? Should it be calculate from back? Also, it will be great if you can a small example in your approach? Helps to increase understanding tremendously.

Comment: @JohnLui Of course, `lds` needs to be computed from the back, and in ascending order.